# Unable to do Server side paging in asp.net web form using DataTable

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, datatables, asp.net-ajax

I am  trying to implement server side paging using jquery datatables in asp.net webform but unable  to call backend method passed in url.

I have **TestServerSidePaging.aspx** page with below html:

```
<div >
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr style="text-align:left;">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>DoB</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr style="text-align:left;">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>DoB</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Script:

```
    $('#example').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax":{
                "url": "TestServerSidePaging.aspx/Test",
                "type": "GET",   
                "data": ""
            }
        });
```

Backend TestServerSidePaging.aspx.cs:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string Test()
    {
        // returns data
    }
```

The method Test()  is not triggered. Is there anything i am missing..

Comment: You have to put your script code in `$(document).ready()`

Comment: And check console of browser, Do you have an error?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `static` to your method. e.g.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Test() { 
   return "test";
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include static  but now including static still i am not able to Trigger Test()

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get it working with the `DataTable ajax:` parameter so I created a work around for you which calls the `[WebMethod]` using `$.ajax` and binds the response to the `DataTable()`.

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class TestServerSidePaging : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static List<Data> Test()
    {
        var d1 = new Data { Name = "Name1", Age = 1, DOB = "27/10/1988" };
        var d2 = new Data { Name = "Name2", Age = 2, DOB = "27/10/1988" };
        var d3 = new Data { Name = "Name3", Age = 3, DOB = "27/10/1988" };
        return new List<Data> { d1, d2, d3 };
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "TestServerSidePaging.aspx/Test",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",  
                success: function (data) {
                    var example = $('#example').DataTable({
                        data: data.d,
                        columns: [
                            { data: "Name" },
                            { data: "Age" },
                            { data: "DOB" }
                        ]
                    });
                },
                error: function (errordata) {
                    console.log(errordata);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table id="example">
            <thead>
                <tr style="text-align:left;">
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>DoB</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr style="text-align:left;">
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>DoB</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```